# error when insrting blob into sqlite table

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, blob

I am simply trying to insert binary data into a blob field and I get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:31)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeUpdate(PrepStmt.java:588)
    at db.DbFunctionsMap.sqlInsertWithBinary(DbFunctionsMap.java:42)
    at maps.MapCacheHelper.cacheMapDef2Db_externalize(MapCacheHelper.java:217)
    at maps.MapCacheHelper.cacheMapDefs(MapCacheHelper.java:185)
```

I have the following code:

```
PreparedStatement prep = connectionWrite.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mapdefcache (identifier,cache) values('myid',?)");
prep.setBytes(1, binarydata);
prep.executeUpdate(sql); <<<< !----------- not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver !
prep.close();
```

binarydata is of type `byte[]`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: and what is the `sql` variable?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your times and thank you very much. Removing the sql as parameter from executeUpdate and its working. Shall I delete this question, because it is stupid. The error comes from copying code ..

Comment: This question might still be helpful for others with the same problem. If you have an answer, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all bothering with this stupid question. First I wanted to delete this question, but maybe someone falls in the same trap.

I copied some code from the "Internet" and mistakenly didn't see that the parameter for prep.executeUpdate is obsolete and thought its the problem of the blob.
So simply 
prep.executeUpdate(); did the trick.